# Java Else If Statements - Code Not Working?

Tags: java, variables, if-statement, conditional-statements

My code is very basic as I started Java this week. However, I cannot seem to get my else if statements working. Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class RestaurantMain {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        //Variables//
        int choice;

        //EndVariables//
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Welcome to the Cooper's restaurant system!");
        System.out.println("How can I help?");
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("1. Customer System");
        System.out.println("2. Management System");
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("Which option do you choose: ");
        choice = in.nextInt();

        if (choice == 1); {
            System.out.println("You have entered the customer system!");
        }

        else if (choice == 2); {
            System.out.println("You have entered the management system!");
        }

    }
}
```

This is the error I am getting:

```
RestaurantMain.java:26: error: 'else' without 'if'
            else if (choice == 2); {
            ^
1 error

Tool completed with exit code 1
```

I have no idea what to do. I am using TextPad and I have had my else if statements (not these ones specifically) work in another file.

Thanks for helping if you can!

Comment: Remove the semicolons between `)` and `{` on the `if` and `else if` lines, like `if (choice == 1) {`.  I guess you're working through some kind of tutorial here. I recommend paying far more attention to little details like this one.

Comment: I converted my answer to a comment, because this question is a "simple typographical error" of the type that should be closed and not answered.

Comment: @DavidWallace Only to watch as others walk off with the loot...

Comment: and assign int choice; to some value when declaring.

Comment: @Poldie and then they lose their loot when the question is closed and deleted.  SO has guidelines about what questions are and aren't welcome here.  This one is unwelcome according to those guidelines.  So I traded in my 10 magic unicorn points for doing the right thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (choice == 1); {
   System.out.println("You have entered the customer system!");
}
```

Remove `;` from that code

Comment: Thank you very much! I definitely need to pay attention to this! I can code in Python so this is all new to me haha